# limited generic type

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a generic class that accepts only two types (i.e., Integers and Doubles), as if I would make the class with only Double type, I would be wasting space when I would use the same class for object having only int fields.

Here is the code:

```
public class Freq implements Comparable {
private String term;
public double frequency;

public String getTerm() {
    return term;
}

public void setTerm(String term) {
    this.term = term;
}

public Freq( String term, int frequency ) {
this.term = term;
this.frequency = frequency;
}

public int compareTo(Object arg) {
    if(this.frequency == ((Freq)arg).frequency)
        return 0;
    else if( this.frequency  >  ((Freq)arg).frequency ) {
        return 1;
    }
    else 
        return -1;
}
```

Now as you can see  this class has the member frequency as double, but I would like
to leave that generic but limited to only doubles and integers. However, if I add the generic type such as `<T extends Number>`, then compareTo method is failing (it says that operator > is not defined on Numbers or T, ...), and I couldnt figure it out why, hence I need your help.

thanks in advance

Comment: If you have T extends Number you are not limited to Ints and Doubles ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make it fully generic by using something like this:

```
public class Freq<N extends Number & Comparable<N>> implements Comparable<Freq<N>> {

  private final N frequency;

  public Freq(N frequency) {
    if (frequency == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("frequency must be non-null");
    }
    this.frequency = frequency;
  }

  public int compareTo(Freq<N> other) {
    return frequency.compareTo(other.frequency);
  }
}
```

**But** if object size is your primary concern, then this might not be the best solution, as you need to store a reference to the wrapper object (`Double` or `Integer`) in addition to the object itself, which is almost certainly larger than just storing a `double` itself.

Thus implementing a simple `Frequency` class that only provides `double` values might actually help safe space.

Comment: +1 for teaching me that you can use '&' like in Freq<N extends Number & Comparable<N>>

Comment: yes, space is my primary concern here. thanks for the code, looks interesting, something I haven't seen before :D

Comment: this would also allow Long and Float

Answer (score 1):

You can't use primitives for generic types.  You can however store any int value in a double, so I would just use a double for everything.

BTW: You may find this simpler

```
public class Freq implements Comparable<Freq>
  public int compareTo(Freq freq) {
    return Double.compare(frequency, freq.frequency);
  }
```

Comment: ok thanx, I was thinking if there was some hack or trick todo that, I was concerned about the space, hence I wanted to modify it that way.

Comment: Objects are allocated on 8-byte boundaries and have a 16-byte header.  It is quite likely that your object will take the same amount of space using double or int and most of it will be overhead. ;) String has an object inside it so an empty string takes 32-bytes min and increases in multiples of 8 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Generics don't mix with primitive types. So either you must use types derived from `Number` (which means you can't use `>` anymore because that works only with primitives) or you can't use generics.

One solution is not to use `int`. `double` is 64bit and can contain any value that `int` can have. Also, since the `int`'s never have a fraction casting from and do double won't cause loss of precision or rounding errors.

So you can write a class `IntFreq` which wraps `Freq` and casts all values accordingly.

Comment: i'm pretty sure this is wrong - double doesn't contain all the ints because of the way it stores values. On the other hand - that's a qn of precision, prob won't matter for an app that uses doubles/ints instead of Big* counterparts anyway.

Comment: `double` stores values as a bit stream plus the position of the comma in the bit stream. It has 56 bits for the mantissa (the bit stream part) so it can store any 32 bit int. Since we never store fractional values when we convert int, you can always convert an int to a double and back without losing prevision.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this.frequency.doubleValue() for the comparison.